# How to implement a method in a DAO?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm using a DAO pattern and Hibernate for my simple JavaFX project for performing CRUD operations. Since I'm new to Hibernate I want to ask you how to implement a particular method.

Firstly I have a solid DAO interface:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public interface Dao<T, ID> {
public T findById(ID id);

public List<T> findAll();

public T save(T entity);

public void delete(T entity);

public void flush();

public void clear();

public void setSession(Session session);
}
```

Then I have another interface (more specific):

```
public interface FotoDao extends Dao<Foto, Integer> {
    public List<Foto> findByCarId(Integer id);
}
```

Followed by another class:

```
import dao.interfaces.Dao;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion;
import utils.HibernateUtil;

public class AbstractDao<T, ID extends Serializable> implements Dao<T, ID> {

private Class<T> persistentClass;
private Session session;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public AbstractDao() {
    this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

public void setSession(Session session) {
    this.session = session;
}

protected Session getSession() {
    if (this.session == null) {
        this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }
    return this.session;
}

public Class<T> getPersistentClass() {
    return persistentClass;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public T findById(ID id) {
    return (T) getSession().load(this.getPersistentClass(), id);
}

@Override
public List<T> findAll() {
    return this.findByCriteria();
}

protected List<T> findByCriteria(Criterion... criterion) {
    Criteria crit = this.getSession().createCriteria(this.getPersistentClass());

    for (Criterion c : criterion) {
        crit.add(c);
    }
    return (List<T>) crit.list();

}

@Override
public T save(T entity) {
    this.getSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    return entity;
}

@Override
public void delete(T entity) {
    this.getSession().delete(entity);
}

@Override
public void flush() {
    this.getSession().flush();
}

@Override
public void clear() {
    this.getSession().clear();
}

}
```

Then finally I have a concrete class:

```
public class FotoHibernateDao extends AbstractDao<Foto, Integer> implements FotoDao {

@Override
public List<Foto> findByCarId(Integer id) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

}
```

How do I implement the `findByCarId(Integer id)` method?

In my data model I have a table which stores foto urls of cars. And I want this
method to return only images associated with a `carId` (which is a foreign key).

Comment: When you already know that you want a CRUD repository, why not let Hibernate implement it for you? [Here](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-two-crud/) is a tutorial that shows how `CrudRepository` works.

Comment: My intention is to attract more experienced hibernate users by making it more visible. If it is not a good practice to do that I would avoid doing it.

Comment: Experienced hibernate users will browse the hibernate tag c; So you can just spell the languages/frameworks you use the normal way.

Comment: Your question boils down to "how do I write and execute queries with Hibernate?". This is of course covered by the documentation. Read it, and try something: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql. Also, the setSession() methodmakes no sense, and the getSession() method should try to store the current session in a field: you always want to use the **current** session. Not the one that was current the first time the DAO was called.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not using spring. I'm making a desktop application.

Comment: `spring != hibernate`. Those are two disjoint frameworks.